# Homomorphic filtering in java

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, image-comparison

Has anyone know the concept and working of  homomorphic filtering and its  java implementation. i need to compare two images . from camera to database . i am using naive similarity algorithm. it is working well. but light changing is a problem. how we can solve the illumination problem.?
 I am stuck at testing.
android 2.2

Comment: What have you tried? Can you provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for a better help.

Comment: i have tried Histogram equalization but not worked. thats all for illumination.

Comment: Heyy i dont have any errors in the app. my problem is light . i dont have a method to solve the light's problem